# Sort each column of 4D array in reverse order

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

Suppose I have this 4D array:

```py
Y = np.random.randint(1, 9, size=(5,1,10,4))
Y.shape
(5, 1, 10, 4)
```

That I want to sort each element of `Y` along the third dimension, in reverse order.

In the given example above, the first 2 elements of `Y` are:

```py
#  first 2 entries of Y
Y[:2]
array([[[[1, 8, 7, 8],
         [8, 2, 7, 3],
         [7, 8, 7, 8],
         [3, 1, 8, 4],
         [3, 1, 2, 2],
         [6, 4, 2, 3],
         [3, 8, 1, 8],
         [1, 7, 3, 2],
         [7, 4, 6, 6],
         [1, 5, 6, 3]]],


       [[[7, 2, 7, 7],
         [4, 8, 5, 5],
         [1, 2, 7, 5],
         [7, 5, 8, 3],
         [6, 4, 2, 4],
         [4, 4, 2, 4],
         [1, 5, 3, 7],
         [4, 5, 3, 3],
         [4, 8, 2, 2],
         [6, 1, 6, 6]]]])
```

The method, `numpy.ndarray.sort()` produces error (plus - [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy.ndarray.sort) method does not have a `reversed` parameter to reverse order after sorting):

```py
Y_sorted_reversed = Y.sort(Y, axis=2)
TypeError: argument for sort() given by name ('axis') and position (position 0)
```

**Required:**

In the given array `Y` above, the sorted (descending) array, `Y_sorted_reversed`'s first two elements should be:

```py
#  first 2 entries of Y_sorted_reversed
Y_sorted_reversed[:2]
array([[[[8, 8, 8, 8],
         [7, 8, 7, 8],
         [7, 8, 7, 8],
         [6, 7, 7, 6],
         [3, 5, 6, 4],
         [3, 4, 6, 3],
         [3, 4, 3, 3],
         [1, 2, 2, 3],
         [1, 1, 2, 2],
         [1, 1, 1, 2]]],


       [[[7, 8, 8, 7],
         [7, 8, 7, 7],
         [6, 5, 7, 6],
         [6, 5, 6, 5],
         [4, 5, 5, 5],
         [4, 4, 3, 4],
         [4, 4, 3, 4],
         [4, 2, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 2, 3],
         [1, 1, 2, 2]]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take an example `k` :

```
import numpy as np
k=np.array([[[[1, 8, 7, 8],
         [8, 2, 7, 3],
         [7, 8, 7, 8],
         [3, 1, 8, 4],
         [3, 1, 2, 2],
         [6, 4, 2, 3],
         [3, 8, 1, 8],
         [1, 7, 3, 2],
         [7, 4, 6, 6],
         [1, 5, 6, 3]]],


       [[[7, 2, 7, 7],
         [4, 8, 5, 5],
         [1, 2, 7, 5],
         [7, 5, 8, 3],
         [6, 4, 2, 4],
         [4, 4, 2, 4],
         [1, 5, 3, 7],
         [4, 5, 3, 3],
         [4, 8, 2, 2],
         [6, 1, 6, 6]]]])

m=np.sort(k,axis=-2)  # axis is -2 will sort all the columns.

#output

array([[[[1, 1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2, 2],
         [1, 2, 2, 3],
         [3, 4, 3, 3],
         [3, 4, 6, 3],
         [3, 5, 6, 4],
         [6, 7, 7, 6],
         [7, 8, 7, 8],
         [7, 8, 7, 8],
         [8, 8, 8, 8]]],


       [[[1, 1, 2, 2],
         [1, 2, 2, 3],
         [4, 2, 2, 3],
         [4, 4, 3, 4],
         [4, 4, 3, 4],
         [4, 5, 5, 5],
         [6, 5, 6, 5],
         [6, 5, 7, 6],
         [7, 8, 7, 7],
         [7, 8, 8, 7]]]])
```

Now do:

```
m[:,:,::-1,:]                 #::-1 to reverse

array([[[[8, 8, 8, 8],
         [7, 8, 7, 8],
         [7, 8, 7, 8],
         [6, 7, 7, 6],
         [3, 5, 6, 4],
         [3, 4, 6, 3],
         [3, 4, 3, 3],
         [1, 2, 2, 3],
         [1, 1, 2, 2],
         [1, 1, 1, 2]]],


       [[[7, 8, 8, 7],
         [7, 8, 7, 7],
         [6, 5, 7, 6],
         [6, 5, 6, 5],
         [4, 5, 5, 5],
         [4, 4, 3, 4],
         [4, 4, 3, 4],
         [4, 2, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 2, 3],
         [1, 1, 2, 2]]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`Y_sorted_reversed = Y.sort(Y, axis=2)`

The above is an incorrect form of calling "sort", it should be...
`Y.sort(axis=2)`
...to get the result you are trying for.

**Problem 1:** The array is sorted in-place, i.e. Y itself is sorted and contains the sorted result, rather than returning the sorted form to Y_sorted_reversed.

**Problem 2:** Y should not be passed as a parameter to Y.sort(...).

If you want to create a sorted copy (which is what it looks like you want to do), instead of calling sort on Y, you would need to call sort on numpy, i.e. `np.sort(Y, axis=2)`

Note: calling `np.flip` disrupts the array more than the OP wants. Hence, `np.sort` seems to have a more suitable effect (corrections on calling sort are valid) but need alternate method for reversing. Can do manual iteration, or reverse using shorthand suggested by another poster, (`y_arr[:,:,::-1,:]`). Something like:

```
y_arr = np.random.randint(1, 9, size=(2,1,10,4))
y_sorted = np.sort(y_arr, axis=2)
y_reversed = y_sorted[:,:,::-1,:]
```

Comment: This doesn't give required answer in a `4D numpy array`. I sorts entire column, not each column of every element of `Y`.

Comment: Hm good point. Seems to be more an issue with the flip operation I suggested. Sort seems to be fine without the flip, yeah?

Comment: Ah, you're right. `np.flip(y_sorted, axis=2)`. Thank you.